# What HTTP client does the Android Webview use?

Tags: android-webview, chromium

I am trying to understand how the webview in Android works. I know that the default http client in Android is HttpUrlConnection which uses okhttp and okio.
But I did some tests and found that the chromium in the webview doesn't use them. My question is: Does webview rely on any client to do the http requests or it has its own implementation for making the http requests?

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose is of your app so I can understand why you need that.

Comment: Absolutely, I am doing research about HTTP Engines and I am trying to change the engine and make the change affect all apps in the system including the ones that use webview. 
I modified the okhttp inside the AOSP but noticed that webview doesn't rely on it to make http requests. Thats why I want to know what http client it uses